# ES6 Class 'this' to be used in non class method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

```
let dispNameExt = () => {
  console.log(this.name);
};

class MyName {
  constructor() {
     this.name = 'lsr';
  }

  dispName() {
    dispNameExt();
  }
}
```

How to make this piece of code work, where in the 'this of the class' is accessed by an external method outside the class.?

Comment: Fortunately you cannot make it work.

Comment: *this* within the "class" is an instance. Which particular instance should the external "this" reference? PS: it will always reference the global object because that is how it's specified.

Comment: If you used a non-arrow function you could call it with `dispNameExt.call(this)`. Arrow functions (deliberately) don't let you set `this` like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let dispNameExt = (model) => {
    console.log(model.name);
};

class MyName {
    constructor() {
       this.name = 'lsr';
    }

    dispName() {
        dispNameExt(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using an arrow function for `dispNameExt`, I believe the only way to do it is to pass the `this` value as a parameter to the function.

```
let dispNameExt = (thisValue) => {
    console.log(thisValue.name);
};
```

But if you change it to use a normal `function`, there are several ways to specify the value for `this` inside a function.

```
function dispNameExt() {
    console.log(this.name);
}

class MyName {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'lsr';
    }

    dispName() {
        // Using .apply()
        dispNameExt.apply(this);

        // Using .call()
        dispNameExt.call(this);

        // Using .bind()
        dispNameExt.bind(this)();
    }
}
```

Comment: @RobG yup I am aware of that, but I don't think it's necessary to modify the existing function. Also, your example of `dispNameExt = dispNameExt.bind(this)()` assigns the return value of the function call to `dispNameExt` instead of assigning the new function with a bound `this` value.

Comment: @RobG haha no worries  ;)

Answer (score 0):

It should be refactored to static prop. Which surely can be accessed wihout instantiating a class.

Since `name` property name [is reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), another property name has to be chosen.

```
let dispNameExt = () => {
  console.log(MyName.title);
};

class MyName {
  static get title() {
     return 'lsr';
  }

  dispName() {
    dispNameExt();
  }
}
```